# How to Add a Line to the Middle of a .txt File in F#

Tags: .net, file-io, f#

I have to add a line to the middle of a .txt file for one of my F# assignments. The file is a record of students in the following format, and each record gets its own line in the file:

[LastName],[FirstName],[MiddleInitial],[Telephone#],[EmailAddress],[GPA]

(Commas separate the data items in case it's hard to tell)

I need to add a student with the last name of "Constant" (there are no other students with the last name of "Constant", so that does make things a bit easier) -- along with his information -- to the .txt file, ensuring that the last names are kept in alphabetical order. In other words, I need to add a new student record to the middle of the file without deleting any existing records, and I'm completely stumped. I don't expect (nor do I want) someone to do my assignment for me, but I would greatly appreciate some pointers.

Comment: You'll find that 1) this question isn't really F#-specific and 2) it has been answered dozens of times over for C#.

Comment: @ildjarn That is a different language though, that WhiteWolf may have no experience with.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox : It's a good starting point – one would read the general approach to solving the problem and see the APIs involved, from which point one would know what documentation to read, etc. Pointers were asked for, pointers were given.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to go around this, and for the time being we will ignore the trickiness of alphabetical sorting by Family name, as well as processing extremely large files. You should definitely study the different ways of [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file) and [writing files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file).

```
open System
open System.IO
let students = @"C:\tmp\students.txt"
let newRec = [|"Constant,Dunham,X,99999,cdx@gmail.com,2.0"|]

students 
|> File.ReadAllLines
|> Array.append newRec
|> Array.sort
|> (fun x -> File.WriteAllLines(students,x))
```

I believe this code is more or less self-explanatory, but let me know if you know need some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

One of the important 'features' of the question is how to read and write a text file.

A good place for small snippets is at [F# Snippets](http://www.fssnip.net), although it is not that easy to go search there if you aren't entirely sure what you are looking for.

Here are two useful functions, originally from a book by Don Syme et al.:

```
open System.IO

/// Read all lines from UTF-8 encoded text file as a sequence.
let linesFromFile filename =
    seq { use reader = File.OpenText filename
          while not reader.EndOfStream
             do yield reader.ReadLine () }

/// Create a new UTF-8 encoded text file and
/// write all lines from a sequence to the new file.
let linesTofile filename (lines: string seq) =
    use writer = File.CreateText filename
    for line in lines
     do writer.WriteLine line
```

That then allows you to focus on writing a function that will take a string sequence and manipulate it to your liking. In psuedo-code:

```
do linesFromFile inputfilename
   |> myStringSeqFunction
   |> linesTofile outputfilename
```

Caveat: In this example the input file and output file are different files; I would solve that at a later opportunity once the important stuff is working, but it is a thing to take note of.

Comment: Why not just `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines`? A good place for documentation is [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file).

Comment: @s952163 I hadn't noticed those methods. They do indeed seem appropriate. :-)